# UnsatisfiedLinkError Android native library

Tags: android, native

I am making use of android native libraries from the framework.

I get the following errors.

```
01-02 00:13:11.659: W/dalvikvm(3932): Shared lib '/system/lib/xxx.so' already opened by CL 0x41fec468; can't open in 0x0

01-02 00:13:11.659: W/dalvikvm(3932): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing xxxx;
```

What does the first error mean? I am loading the library only once. But still i get this error. Does that mean some other application is loading the library as well. If that is the case how do i handle this problem.

For the second error, the path name gets messed up. Actually i have the class java file from a sample android ndk project and copied it in mine. And seems that it is referencing the original file path instead of the updated file path from my project.

Comment: psot the code where you load the lib.

Comment: package android.media.xx;
import android.xx;
import android.xx;
import android.xx;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.media.xx;

/**
 * @hide
 */
public class GLEnvironment {
 
 static {
       System.load("/system/lib/libxx.so");
     }

    private int glEnvId;
....

Comment: Its been sometime i have been trying to resolve this. Ofcourse my understanding of the java is not good so may be i am missing few things. Please let me know if you have some suggestions.